# Apache enabling dump_io for dav_svn

Tags: apache, mod-dav-svn

To debug an issue I'm having I need an Apache + Subversion server which dumps all requests and responses into a log file. This is not meant for production, that's why authentication is disabled as well.

I'm stuck with dump_io, my error.log does not contain requests/responses.

Here's the relevant setup.

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y apache2
RUN apt-get install -y subversion libapache2-mod-svn libsvn-dev
RUN apt-get install -y less nano
RUN a2enmod dav
RUN a2enmod dav_svn
RUN a2enmod dump_io
RUN printf "DumpIOInput On\nDumpIOOutput On\nLogLevel debug" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN service apache2 restart

COPY dav_svn.conf /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.conf
COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

RUN mkdir -p /var/local/svn
RUN svnadmin create /var/local/svn/myrepo
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/local/svn
RUN chmod -R 775 /var/local/svn

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

dav_svn.conf

```
<Location /svn/>
  DAV svn
  DavDepthInfinity on

  SVNParentPath /var/local/svn/

  Satisfy Any
  Allow from all
  DirectorySlash Off

  LogLevel debug
</Location>
```

000-default.conf (this is the default, I only added the LogLevel line)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn
        LogLevel debug

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Put the three files in a folder and

```
docker build -t svn-server .
docker run -it -p 3570:80 --rm svn-server
curl http://localhost:3570/svn/myrepo
```

After making the request I would expect `/var/log/apache2/error.log` to contain the full response of `GET /svn/myrepo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a night of sleep and some RTFM I found the solution.

I sprinkled some

```
LogLevel dumpio:trace7
```

all over and it works.

Why that isn't the default is beyond me. You have to enable/disable `DumpIOInput` and `DumpIOOutput` anyway.

> Additionally, mod_dumpio needs to be configured to LogLevel trace7:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dumpio.html

Comment: thanks alot, this answer saved my night :D